# Javascript code works fine to download images but not to download a PDF file

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, download

The following code works properly to download remote images, but did not work when altering it to download remote PDF file, here is the code I am using:

```
<a href="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" data-remote>Remote PDF</a>

 <script defer type="text/javascript">
    const a = document.querySelector('a[data-remote]')
    a.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const file = await fetch(e.target.href);
      const blob = await file.blob();
      const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
      downloadLink.href = blobUrl;
      downloadLink.download = 'file.pdf';

      downloadLink.click();
    })
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `download` property to `a` tag and remove the script to download the pdf.

```
<a href="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" download >Remote PDF</a>
```

Or if you want to use js to download it, consider to add `mode:'no-cors'` when you fetch

Comment: Download property is not working in php file I am using and I dont know how to implement mode:'no-cors'  :/

Comment: Hi, I think the problem was the cors policy where the pdf is stored, which is www.w3.org . I think your code is working, it's just the pdf source policy who don't allow you to download it.  You can try to use free cors proxy like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ , to test your code, hope this help

Comment: OMG!!! I spent lot of time in this issue, and finally you are right, the problem is in the source policy, thanks a lot :)